# Products not displaying on frontend when disabling MSI - Magento Multi Stock Inventory

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

I have completely removed MSI from the Magento installation, all the modules involved have been removed through Composer:

```
"replace": {
        "magento/module-inventory": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-requisition-list": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-advanced-checkout": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-export-stock": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-export-stock-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-setup-fixture-generator": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-cache": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog-search": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-indexer": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configuration": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-indexer": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-indexer": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-multi-dimensional-indexer-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-product-alert": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-reservations": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-reservations-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales-frontend-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-shipping": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-source-selection": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*"
}
```

I have then Upgraded, Compiled and deployed statics. I have also reindexed and cleaned all cache. Logs have been checked without any luck.

I have checked the database trying to find fields related to the MSI that didn't get deleted or that they were needed in order to add a product, but couldn't find any.

If I install them again, create a source and then add stock for that source, the products appear in the frontend.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: have you ran a reindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have got them all?

```
 "replace": {
    "magento/inventory-composer-installer":"*",
    "magento/inventory-composer-metapackage":"*",
    "magento/module-inventory": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-advanced-checkout": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-requisition-list": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-cache": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-search": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configuration": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-export-stock": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-export-stock-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-frontend": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-multishipping": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-quote": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-quote-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-sales": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-sales-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-sales-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-shipping": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-shipping-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-webapi-extension": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-multi-dimensional-indexer-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-product-alert": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservations": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservations-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-frontend-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-setup-fixture-generator": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-shipping": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-selection": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*"
}
```

You can also use [this module](https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory) by Yireo.

```
composer require yireo/magento2-replace-inventory
```

Comment: This is the exact same list I shared...

Comment: Hi @Raül sorry it now has 20 more items ;-)

Comment: Hi Stevie, I ended up reinstalling with a new DB and it worked straight out of the box. I guess i had some installation issues that didn't allow me to work without MSI. Still, thanks for the answer :D